# How to execute NFC commands without removing the tag from the HF field between commands in Android?

Tags: android, nfc

I am trying to execute NFC commands without removing the tag from the HF field between commands.  In other words, once the user places the Android phone or tablet in the vicinity of the tag, the user should be able to use one command after another without first removing the phone or tablet before the next command.

Answer (score 1):

This always possible. No special action is needed.